# Input-Looping Matrix Dimensions Must Agree

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I've got this error:

```
    Error using  - Matrix dimensions must agree.
    Error in DistMatrix3 (line 23)
       d=sqrt((I-L').^2+(J-M').^2+(K-N').^2);

    Error in coba (line 20)
        d=DistMatrix3(cobat,c);   % calculate the distance
```

And here my code:

---

I think the error isn't because of the DistMatrix3 itself. It is caused by `c` inputs, the looping input. And I guess these lines that should be fixed since it doesn't contain `j` variables:

```
for i=1:k
    f=find(g==i);
    if f                % calculate the new centroid 
        c(i,:)=mean(cobat(find(g==i),:),1);
    end
end
```

I'm stuck on how I should fix it. Can you guys tell me what should I do to solve this? Your help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: As the error message says, the matrix dimensions of ``I`` & ``L'`` or ``J`` & ``M'`` or ``K`` & ``N'`` don't agree. This causes the subtraction to fail. And hence DistMatrix3. So you have to figure out where these discrepancies come from.

Comment: The error message seems to suggest that the error is being thrown at `d=DistMatrix3(cobat,c);   % calculate the distance`? In particular, it's because one/more of the matrices (`I`,`L'`,`J`,`M'`,`K`,`N'`) that are used to calculate `d` are not the same size

Comment: -1 : The whole issue seems to have been discussed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/74791) - what are the results of that discussion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code :

```
[maxRow, maxCol]=size(cobat);
for i=1:k
    for j=1:maxCol
        c=input('Enter a number: '); % sequential initialization
    end
end
```

seems unlikely to be correct.

Should this be something like:

```
[maxRow, maxCol]=size(cobat);
for i=1:k
    for j=1:maxCol
        c(i,j)=input('Enter a number: '); % sequential initialization
    end
end
```

I'm also wondering whether user input k should actually always equal maxRow.